# T-SQL: Conditionally joining using a parameter

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, join, conditional-statements

Consider a simple join:

```
Select TableB.* 
From TableA 
Inner Join TableB 
    On TableB.ID = TableA.ID
```

What I want to do is decide which table to join to depending on a parameter. Although the following syntax is not valid, I wrote it just to illustrate what I am after:

```
Select TableD.* 
From TableA 
Inner Join 
    [If @useTableC = 1 Then Join to TableC Else Join to TableB] As TableD
```

Both TableB and TableC have identical columns.

How can I create this kind of join. Please be aware that this example is actually a small portion of a much larger query so you cannot just use If...Else statements.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Usually I'd prefer to rewrite in more than one statement, but if you really need it:

```
SELECT td.*
FROM TableA ta
JOIN (
    SELECT tc.* FROM TableC Where @useTableC = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT tb.* FROM TableB Where @useTableC = 0
) td ON ( /* JOIN CONDITION MISSING */)
```

Comment: When this UNION is executed and @useTableC = 1, does SQL Server still go through and process ALL the records in TableB? If so, it would be a terrible waste of processing time.

Comment: There's no IO penalty, @AndroidDev: when `@useTableC = 1`, the SQL Server does not read any row of TableB.

Comment: Why would it not read any rows from TableB? I don't see how that's possible. The records in TableB will only get excluded after they have been retrieved and THEN the Where clause has been applied.

Comment: @AndroidDev The query engine is not obliged to process clauses of the query in the order they are written; it is only obliged to come up with the correct answer. The query engine is *very* clever. How the query engine decides what to do is a deep and (IMO) fascinating area with lots to read and learn :)

Comment: The condition `Where @useTableC = 1` is a scalar condition over two constants (in regards to the `SELECT` statement). That means that this condition is only evaluated once, and SQL can safely remove the table from the query plan. See more information about [Compile Time Expression Evaluation] (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175933.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, T-SQL has no syntax to support this. I tinkered with this some time ago and couldn't come up with a solution, until I found this article that helped me (by using Left Outer joins) and it might help you. It is located [here](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2007/04/03/Conditional-Joins.aspx).

Comment: Your solution would be great if all I had were a few conditional tables. But I could end up having dozens of tables, so using Left Outer joins would be a serious performance issue.

Answer (score 0):

@Gerardo Lima's answer is excellent, but as an alternative you could build up your query with dynamic SQL.  This would let you use a series of if statements to add, or not, as many joins as you wish using as many if statements as needed.  As a coarse and rough example:

```
declare @sql varchar(8000)

set @sql = 'Select TableD.*  From TableA '

if @usertableC = 1 
then select @sql = @sql + ' innner join tableC'

if @usertableC != 1
then select @sql = @sql + ' innner join tableB

exec @sql
```

There is a good discussion of dynamic sql at ["the curse and blessing of dynamic sql"](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html)

Comment: Dynamic sql often does better with query plans than the union approach above, which may store the "A" plan when the proc is first run, and always use the "A" plan even when it should use "B"

Comment: Hi, @BrianWhite, you got a valid point here, but the reuse of an unnefficient query plan can be avoided by using the query hint `RECOMPILE` or the `WITH RECOMPILE` stored procedure option. (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181714.aspx)

Comment: @GerardoLima You are entirely right, but the optimizer tries to reuse query plans for a reason.  I would only suggest including a query hint like that if you really have some reason to suspect the cached plan will be ineffecient (rare, but it does happen) or for certain performance testing purposes.  I would not use query hints like that lightly.

Comment: If you're using with recompile does that gain you anything that either plain dynamic SQL or parameterized queries doesn't give you?   @Tim - you would definitely have reason to suspect that the first plan may not be universal when one of the parameters is useTableC :)

Answer (score 0):

Nice solution, Geraldo! There is not be a performance hit on using the union. I can't tell you why (perhaps someone can fill in the gaps here), but the execution plan shows 0 I/O cost for the constant scan.

However, this does approach depend on the schemas for TableB and TableC being identical. To do this with multiple statements, supporting disparate schemas in TableB and TableC, I'd consider the following approach:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @sql = 'SELECT td.* FROM TableA ta INNER JOIN Table' + 
    CASE WHEN @useTableC = 1 THEN 'C' ELSE 'B' END + ' td ON ta.ID = td.ID'
EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

Note that it would then be up to your application code to determine the corresponding schema and read the data accordingly.

Comment: Hi, @Peter, you raised a valid point here: the solution I proposed is not correct if the table schemas are not compatible. The solution, though, can be simpler: only the selected columns must be compatible, hence, any incompatibilities between the `TableC` and `TableB` could be solved into the `SELECT` clause.